# validation form is not working in codeigniter if the dynamic field are generated by drop down

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, validation

There is a drop down text box for type which contains two options
as

1.Tracking Url + Image and 2. Code.

If I select the Tracking Url + Image , then I add two option tracking url and image 
and I select the code then I add js_api_code

When I check if the tracking url already exists by call back validation then the error is invisible and the tracking url and image option are also invisible and the end user does not know the actual problem

Also when I validate it by j query validation it does not work

```
<form onsubmit="return checktrackingurl();" method="post" action="add_content" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="banner">
            <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
             <?php echo form_error('content_type_id'); ?>
            </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Content Type<font color="red">*</font>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <select id="super_category_id" class="form-control" id="content_type_id" name='content_type_id' readonly>
        <?php foreach($content_type as $content_type)
        { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $content_type['content_type_id']; ?>"><?php echo $content_type['content_type']; ?>
                </option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>   
              <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
                       <?php echo form_error('title'); ?>
              </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Title<font color="red">*</font>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="<?php echo set_value('title'); ?>">
        </div>
        </div>

            <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
                       <?php echo form_error('selectwhat'); ?>
             </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Type <font color="red">*</font>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select name="selectwhat" class="form-control" id="selectwhat">
                        <option value="">Select type</option>
                        <option value="tracking"> Tracking URL + Image</option>
                        <option value="jsapicode"> Code</option>
                    </select>   
        </div>
        </div>
            <div id="trackingid"></div>
            <div id="codeid"></div>
            <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">              
        <?php echo form_error('description'); ?>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Description
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                <textarea  class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description"><?php echo set_value('description');?></textarea>
        </div>
        </div> 
          <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
        <?php echo form_error('steps[]'); ?>
          </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Steps<font color="red">*</font>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="steps[]" placeholder="steps" value="<?php echo set_value('steps[]'); ?>">  <span style="font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;" onclick="addMoreRows(this.form);" > Add More</span>
                </div> 
              </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div id="addedRows">
                </div>
        </div>
             </div> 
<!--            <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
          <?php //echo form_error('callback_url'); ?>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        CallBack Url
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="callback_url" placeholder="Callback Url" value="http://182.73.146.18/staging/iRupee/rewarduser.php?offer_id={offer_id}&affiliate_id={affiliate_id}&clickId={aff_sub}" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>-->
<!--            <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
            <?php //echo form_error('term_condition'); ?>
            </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Term Condition
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="term_condition" placeholder="Term Condition" value="<?php //echo set_value('term_condition'); ?>">
        </div>
        </div>-->
             <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
            <?php echo form_error('city'); ?> 
             </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        City
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo set_value('city'); ?>">
        </div>
        </div>
             <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
            <?php echo form_error('daily_limit'); ?>
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Daily Limit <font color="red">*</font>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daily_limit" placeholder="Daily Limit" value="<?php echo set_value('daily_limit'); ?>">
        </div>
        </div>
            <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
            <?php echo form_error('cashback_amount'); ?>
            </div>     
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Cashback Amount <font color="red">*</font>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cashback_amount" placeholder="Cashback Amount" value="<?php echo set_value('cashback_amount'); ?>">
        </div>
        </div>
            <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
            <?php echo form_error('priority'); ?>
            </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Priority
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select name="priority" class="form-control " >
                        <option value="">select Priority</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div style="color:red;padding:5px;">
         <?php echo form_error('status'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Offer Status
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                <select  class="form-control " name='status'>
        <option value="">Select Status</option>

        <option value="1">Active
                </option>
        <option value="0">Deactive
                </option>
        </select>  

        </div>
        </div>  
             <div style="color:red;padding:5px;"> 
             <?php echo form_error('title_image'); ?>
             </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                    Select Title Image
        </label>  
                    <div class="col-sm-4">    

                <input type="file" class="filestyle" name="title_image" data-buttonText="Find Image">          

          </div>        
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
        Push Notification 
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select  class="form-control " name='push_status'>
        <option value="1">Yes
                </option>
                <option value="0" selected>No
                </option>
        </select>  

        </div>
        </div> 




<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" size="12px;">
Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</button>
    <input type="button" value="Go Back" size="8px;" onclick="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" style=""/>  
</div>
        </form>
```

The javascript code that populate the tracking url + image and js_api_code as below

```
function selectwhat()
    {
    var selectwhat=$('#selectwhat').val();

    if(selectwhat=='tracking')
    {


   var rowTrackingUrl='<p id="newtracking"><div style="color:red;padding:5px;"><?php echo form_error('tacking_url'); ?>\
                      </div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >\
                      Tracking Url<font color="red">*</font></label>\
                      <div class="col-sm-5">\
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tacking_urls"  name="tacking_url" required placeholder="Tarcking Url" value="<?php echo set_value('tacking_url'); ?>">\
                       </div></div>\
                       <div style="color:red;padding:5px;"><?php echo form_error('image'); ?></div>\n\
                       <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >Select Image<font color="red">*</font></label>\n\
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="file" class="filestyle" name="image" required  data-buttonText="Find Image">\n\
                      </div></div></p>';
    jQuery("#trackingid").html(rowTrackingUrl);
    }
    if(selectwhat=='jsapicode')
    {
    var rowJsapicode='<p id="newjsapicode"><div style="color:red;padding:5px;">\
            <?php echo form_error('js_api_code'); ?>\
            </div>\
        <div class="form-group">\
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >\
        Js Api Code<font color="red">*</font>\
        </label>\
        <div class="col-sm-5">\
                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="js_api_code" required placeholder="Js Api Code" ><?php echo set_value('js_api_code'); ?></textarea>\
        </div>\
        </div></p>';   
       jQuery("#trackingid").html(rowJsapicode); 
    }
    }

        $(document).on('change','#selectwhat',$(this),selectwhat);
```

The form validation code for tracking url like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('tacking_url', 'Tracking Url', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_tracking_url');
 public function check_tracking_url()
    {
               $this->db->where('content_type_id', $_POST['content_type_id']);
               $this->db->where('tacking_url', $_POST['tacking_url']);
               $result = $this->db->get('offer_content');
               if($result->num_rows() > 0)
               {
                  $this->form_validation->set_message('check_tracking_url','Combination of tracking url and content tye is already exist'); // set your message
                  return false;
               }
               else{ return true;}
    }
```

I am unable to this I tried jquery validation like this

```
function checktrackingurl()
    {
      var tacking_url=  $('#tacking_urls').val();
      var content_type_id=$('#super_category_id').val();
      if(typeof tacking_url!= "undefined")
      { 
      var  url= "<?php echo base_url() ?>checktrackingurl";
      var  data='tacking_url='+tacking_url+"&content_type_id="+content_type_id;
       $.post(url,data,function(msg){
          var status=$.trim(msg);

          if(status=='alreadyExist')
          {
          alert("The combination of Tracking Url and Content Type already exist");
          return false;
          }
          else if(status=='notExist'){
          alert('hi');
            return true;
        }
    });

      }
    else{
        alert();
    }

    }
```

Comment: We would like to help you. But to do that, you should provide a working demo on codepen.io or something like that.

Comment: i provide all ready above my work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select name="selectwhat" class="form-control" id="selectwhat">
                        <option value="">Select type</option>
                        <option value="tracking"> Tracking URL + Image</option>
                        <option value="jsapicode"> Code</option>
                    </select>

 </div>`

**chnage To below and call you jquery according this may help you**

`<div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select name="selectwhat" class="form-control" id="selectwhat">
                        <option value="" <?php echo set_select('selectwhat', '', true);?>>Select type</option>
                        <option value="tracking" <?php echo set_select('selectwhat', 'tracking');?> > Tracking URL + Image</option>
                        <option value="jsapicode" <?php echo set_select('selectwhat', 'jsapicode');?> > Code</option>
                    </select>

        </div>`

**add this to Your jquery**

```
$(function(){
     selectwhat();
  });
```

i think this will help you